# How to view all system generated Intents?

Tags: android, android-intent, onhover

Is there a way to view all intents that are generated by the Android OS's at any moment but maybe filtered by the activity ? Specifically I am testing the onHoverListener -  I want to know if my activity is throwing away the hover motionevent or whether none is being generated (system not capable/ some other problem)

Ideally I would like a log of all intents given to my activity - but some other trick is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

Android intents are , capable for starting a new activity , service , complete any action i.e send email , click photo , fetch data from a content provider etc . 
Capturing any intent of that kind , you need to have intent filters registered to your activity with the same actions , as that of system intents .[The framework will pick your actvity/app if the same intent is fired and hence you may be able to intercept those intents if the user prefers to] This may be little too much as there will be so many of the actions declared for different android components .But some popular examples are sending sms , picking a contact , send mail .
Please refer to this for more info :http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

Events and Intents are different all together , all events generated by your app will go the event handler queue of the UI thread . 
So in order to intercept you should set appropriate event listeners to your activity components .

Comment: Ah yes , sorry for the confusion between Intents and Events - what I mean is I have a onHoverListener and it is NOT picking up the hover event - I want to know if it is because it is missing some necessary intent filter (I do not have access to Manifest)

Comment: Listeners have nothing to do with the intent filters

Comment: Will a onHoverListener work without necessary Intent Filters in Manifest for that activity ?

Comment: Yes , these hoverListener and intent filters are not related at all

Answer (score 0):

Try using onTouch instead .
setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

```
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            //Button Pressed
        }
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
             //finger was lifted
        }
        return false;
    }`
```